# Loop to get mysql values with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm stuck on the model side where I have to write a loop that select some certain values from mysql. The table looks like this:

```html
0      2016-11-06 08:36:19
7300   2016-11-06 08:43:11
19200  2016-11-06 08:43:12
35980  2016-11-06 08:43:17
45600  2016-11-06 08:43:21
45820  2016-11-06 08:43:27
45840  2016-11-06 08:43:28
45860  2016-11-06 08:43:29
26940  2016-11-06 08:44:34
19760  2016-11-06 08:44:36
3440   2016-11-06 08:44:38
0      2016-11-06 08:44:44
1400   2016-11-06 08:46:00
7120   2016-11-06 08:46:04
11240  2016-11-06 08:46:06
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:10
11240  2016-11-06 08:46:11
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:12
3940   2016-11-06 08:46:51
0      2016-11-06 08:46:56
```

Basically this are entries generated from a weighting machine and inserted in my database works like this :

When something is on the weighing machine, the entries will start to update from 0 to the real weight of the object on the weight machine, but till they get to the real weight I get all the values going up. When the difference on 3-4 the entries is less than 50kg, we are at the real weight. Then the weight will drop to 0 again, and will start the same cicle when something is on it. From the above example, these are the entries I am interested in:

```html
45840  2016-11-06 08:43:28
11220  2016-11-06 08:46:10
```

I was thinking to compare each entry with the following one, and when the difference is less than 50 kg for 3 entries, get one of the entries and continue like this for other ones, but I don't how exactly I can do this in PHP.

```html
$sql = "SELECT weight, added_date FROM balance_events WHERE added_date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          $result = $query->result();
          for weight in result:
          // TO DO the loop
          return $result;
```

How do I make my for loop in order to get the desired output? Also is there a way to check the timestamp on the added_date in order constrain the time of the weight event (0 to 0) to be more than 5 minutes, and to ignore the ones that have the duration under 5min?

Answer (score 0):

By assuming your query is right

```
$sql = "SELECT weight, added_date FROM balance_events WHERE added_date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result();

$max = 0;

foreach( $result as $one )
{
    if( $one > $max )
    {
        $max = $one;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
return $max;
```

Comment: This will only get 1 value, for any date interval, but like in the example I need  / each interval 0 to 0 to get 1 value, if I try with my example this will only output 45860  2016-11-06 08:43:29, I think that you have to reset each time you get a value and make some sort of list.

Answer (score 0):

Here the query to get the values by for loop and condition to get above 5 minutes.

```
       $sql = "SELECT weight, added_date, MINUTE(added_date) As minute FROM balance_events WHERE added_date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."'";
                  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                  foreach($query->result() as $row){
                      if($row->minute > 5){
                          echo $weight=$row->weight;
                          echo $added_date=$row->added_date;
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: What should I return from this ?

Comment: query will returns the values with greater then 5 minutes condition